# Problemas inicias Setup

Tags: python

[image: Problema com instalação.]

Pessoal, novo na programação e estou com dificuldades de fazer a instalação do Python. Comando não reconhece o python que está instalado.

Comment: Mas o python está instalado? Se sim, verifique se a variável de ambiente PATH foi atualizada adicionando o caminho do executável dele.

Comment: Ao invés de `python --version`, `py --version` funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente você não marcou a opção para adicionar o python como comando padrão do cmd o qual fica localizado lá em baixo: Add Python 3.8 to PATH:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se não resolver pesquisa no youtube.